# Is there an algorithm to determine proper subsets of items in a list in less than O(n^2) complexity?

Tags: ruby, string, algorithm, set

I have a list of strings. For example: `["stri", "string", "st", "abcd", "bc"]`.

I want to find the smallest set of strings whose members are substrings in the original set. So for the above example, that would be: `["st","bc"]`.

Here is a naive implementation in ruby:

```
terms = ...

subset = terms.reject do |s1|
  terms.any? do |s2|
    s1.include?(s2) && s1 != s2
  end
end
```

Comment: `stri` is a substring of `string`, it should be in the result, no ?

Comment: You can do in in `O(total-number-of-letters-in-all-words)` time for a const-size alphabet, but the algorithm is not trivial. See (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_tree).

Comment: @AlexD, please provide an explanation for how a Suffix tree could be used to answer the question. My intuition tells me it's an NP-complete problem.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Why is it NP-complete if a polynomial solution suggested by the OP? Regarding the suffix trees. We can build a tree `T` for all the words in linear time. Then for every word `w` we check if it exists as a suffix `s`, `s!=w`, in `T`.

Comment: @AlexD, isn't `s!=w` a linear operation by itself ? It will still make the complexity quadratic.

Comment: @AlexD, I misunderstood the question. I (incorrectly) interpreted it to be: if `S` is a set of strings, find smallest subset `T` of `S` such that every string in `S` is a substring of at least one element of `T`, which is a hard problem.

Comment: @user1952500 Let's say `N` is a sum of lengths of all strings (`N=18` in our case). We build the tree in `O(N)` time. Lets say `word0` has length `lenght0`. With help of `T`, we check if `word0` is a substring of another string in `O(length0)`. So for all words, we have `O(length0 + ... + length4) == O(N)`.  So `O(N) + O(N) == O(N)` at the end.

Comment: @AlexD, How do you search that  that `word0` is a substring of another string in `O(length0)` ? I assume you loop through all source strings and check for equality ? So it should be `O(length0 * N)` for word0, correct ?

Comment: @CarySwoveland Ah, I see :)... But in the current interpretation, do you agree that a suffix tree would give us `O(length-of-all-words`) time?

Comment: I don't understand the question. Neither does @Baldrick. If `S` is the set of all strings, do you mean you want the smallest subset `T` of `S` such that every string in `S` contains a substring in at least one element of `T`? If so, what is the significance of "proper" in the title. Suppose the strings were `["a", "b", "bb"]`. What would be the smallest subset? If it were `["a", "b"]`, you are permitting a string (`"a"`) that is not a proper substring of any string in the set.

Comment: @user1952500 No. This is why we build the suffix tree first. Then we go from the root of the suffix tree, one character at a time, to see if we have corresponding substring in one of the words.

Comment: @AlexD, thanks for the info. I'll read up on suffix-trees. Thanks!

Comment: @AlexD, I'll answer your question as soon as I understand the OP's question.

Comment: @CarySwoveland My understanding is (I can be wrong of course) that we are looking for all strings which are substrings of another string in the set. So I agree with  Baldrick's comment.

Comment: @Baldrick `stri` is substring of `string`, but `st` is substring of `stri` (and `string`).  I want the smallest number of total elements where NONE of the elements are substrings another element of the set.

Comment: Does a suffix-tree apply when the substring match could by anywhere within the string? The matches aren't necessarily anchored to the beginning or end.

Comment: @JRideout Yes, suffix-trees apply for substrings, not just for prefixes or suffixes.

Answer (score 1):

The closest I can find is [Aho-Corasick](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aho%E2%80%93Corasick_algorithm), which tries to match a set of patterns in a text simultaneously in O(m+n) time.  If you join the strings in your list together into a common string, any pattern that matches more than once (all of them match at least once, with themselves) is someone's proper substring.

That said, the up-front costs can be fairly heavy for small problems, if I remember correctly.